# Use ES6 library in Ember-cli project

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a small EmberJS application that uses Ember-Cli. My application has a private ES6 library that is a bower dependency. Basically, what I want is to import the library and use it wherever I want.

If I'm not wrong, I should transpile the library in my `brocfile.js` and use it afterwards. Unfortunately, I cannot provide too much concrete information but I'll try my best to be the clearer possible.

My external library is named `main-lib` and is structured the following way (it is working in another project):

- bower_components

  - main-lib

    - api.js
    - main.js
    - message.js

In the main.js file, I have the following:

```
import Api from 'main/api';
import Message from 'main/message';

var main = {};

main.api = Api;
main.message = Message;

export default main;
```

So, what I want to do, is, in my application, to import `main` and use the different functions it contains.

Example, in a certain emberjs controller:

```
import Main from 'main';

//use Main here
```

To do so, I thought of doing the following in my brocfile.js

```
var tree = 'bower_components/main-lib';
var ES6Modules = require('broccoli-es6modules');
var amdFiles = new ES6Modules(tree, {
  format: 'amd',
  bundleOptions: {
    entry: 'main.js',
    name: 'mainLib'
  }
});
```

However, this does nothing. Basically, I want the transpiled files to be included in `vendor.js` or somewhere where I would be able to use the library by importing it.

There's something I'm missing here but I can't pinpoint it.

**Edit1:** After adding these lines at the end of my brocfile.js:

```
mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees')

module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), amdFiles]);
```

I can get an ES5 that looks like this:

```
define(['main/api', 'main/message'], function(api, message) {

    var main = {};

    main.api = Api;
    main.message = Message;

    var _main = main;
    return _main;
});
```

The problem is that it does not import `main/api` and `main/message` as well. Do I have to repeat the code for each file that I want ?

Also, the file is not concatenated in `vendor.js` but simply but at the root of `/dist`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following: `import Api from 'main/api'` - but I don't see a folder called `main` in what you've explained - only a folder called `main-lib` ...

Could it be that `main/api` and `main/message` are not included because they actually don't exist? You might need to use `main-lib/api` and `main-lib/message` in your `main.js` file

Comment: The hierarchy is as follows main-lib / (main.js | api.js | message.js) Should I just have `import api` then ?

Comment: I would expect "import Api from './api'" to work just like it does in Ember.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer, it's shaped more like a comment than an answer.

I generally use merge tree to import all the code in however there is an easier option now using:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-es6modules

Answer (score 2):

The integration of Broccoli with ember-cli already includes a transpiler, so I think something like this should be enough:

```
app.import('bower_components/main-lib/main.js', {
  type: 'vendor',
  exports: { 'main': ['default'] }
);
```

And then you can:

```
import Main from 'main';
```

---

With what you currently have in your Brocfile you still need to merge your `amdFiles` (`app.import` would do that for you).

Something like:

```
mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees')


module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), amdFiles]);
```

---

None of this is tested, but you get the idea.

Comment: Doing the first thing you mentioned, that is app.import, puts the content of main.js in the vendor.js file but does not transpile it....

Comment: If I keep my previous code and add the second part of your answer, the code does not find itself in the vendor.js file...

Answer (score 2):

Ember seem to be [advocating](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2949#issuecomment-85655741) using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-es6modules

This would mean importing your module would look something like:

```
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

var tree = './bower_components/main-lib';
var ES6Modules = require('broccoli-es6modules');
var amdFiles = new ES6Modules(tree, {
  format: 'amd',
  bundleOptions: {
    entry: 'main.js',
    name: 'main-lib'
  }
});

module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), amdFiles])
```

Comment: @etiennenoel did you try this method?