# ES6 lib with named exports in ./vendor dir

Tags: ember.js

Ember 2.0 / ember-cli 1.13.8

I couldn't find a way to import names export from ES6 module located in ./vendor dir in my Ember 2.0 project.

- simple
  `import {Socket} from 'vendor/phoenix'` in my Controller does not transpile the lib into ES5

---

- `app.import('vendor/phoenix.js', {exports: {phoenix: ['Socket']}})` in my `ember-cli-build.js` does not transpile the lib into ES5 either.

---

- I have also tried
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29659509/255633 --

  1. could not make it work due to named exports. (``` Error: Entry module can only have named exports in strict mode (pass ``strict: true``) ```
  2. When I just modify the library to use `default export` the error went away but the library was not available for import. Looks like Broccoli didn't merge the lib into the tree.

here is my `ember-cli-build.js` :

```
  var tree = './vendor';
  var amdFiles = new ES6Modules(tree, {
    format: 'amd',
    bundleOptions: {
      entry: 'phoenix.js',
      name: 'phoenix'
    }
  });

  return mergeTrees([app.toTree(), amdFiles]);
```

Comment: can you point to which lib you are using what is phoenix.js? it might not be exported correctly.

Comment: I am trying to use https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/web%2Fstatic%2Fjs%2Fphoenix.js

Comment: looks find to me... ill try to make a simple app and see if a can import it or produce the same issue

Comment: @TBourque thanks a lot! I spend few hours looking for the solution..

Comment: Ok I believe that i figured out the issue.. posting answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import an ES6 file into an ember app you need to have ember run the file through the transpiler so to do this you can simply do the import in your controller. The issue is that ember needs to have the file in the app folder in order to be able to import it.

So place the JavaScript file inside the app folder under say:

```
app/phoenixjs
```

then in your controller:

```
import phoenix from 'PROJECTNAME/phoenixjs/phoenix
```

then you can use the phoenix object anywhere in that file.

**working Proof:**

[image: Chrome Debug Tools Proof]

**EDIT**

being able to use a named import by

```
import {Socket} from 'import-test-app/extends/phoenix';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  test:Socket.name
});
```

in the template test is "Socket"

Comment: Yeah, you absolutely right here. The only problem is that I still cannot do `named` import. Only `default`. It worked but only I  **modified** the library to combine all `named` import into one big `default` one.

Comment: i was able to do a named import like this:

Comment: import {Socket} from 'import-test-app/extends/phoenix';

Comment: Hey, you are absolutely right! I guess my problem was that I put the `phoenix.js` into `utils` which was picked up by Ember resolver. Thanks a ton!